# How to make UIPageControl overlap home indicator at the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol, iphone-x

When I add a UIPageControl to UIPageViewController, the constraint bottom of UIPageViewController not working, and `UIPagecontrol` was pushed into safe area.

Image:
[image: before add <code>UIPageControl</code>]
and 
[image: affter add <code>UIPageControl</code>]

How to make UIPageControl overlap home indicator at the bottom of the screen [image: like this].

[Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/controls/page-controls/)

My code to add `UIPageControl`

```
private func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
    appearance.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3034487963, green: 0.2256524563, blue: 0.2956835628, alpha: 1)
}
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    setupPageControl()
    return self.orderViewController.count
}

func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the auto-layout constraints may have been set so your bottom alignment is to the safe area rather than the superview. If you want it to overlap, you can align it with the superview, e.g.,

1. align center y to superview
2. equal height to superview